# In Visual Studio Community 7, how do I stop Tab from creating spaces?

Tags: visual-studio, tabs, space

I'm using VS Community 7.4.3. Lots of answers to this question seem only to deal with full regular Visual Studio, and tell you to go to the Tools -> Options -> Text Editor. But there is no "options" menu under my Tools dropdown in VS Community. I have a menu for Text Editor in Preferences. And an option called "Backspace removes indentation." But I select and unselect this--no matter what, when I press Tab, it creates 4 individual spaces.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

"Preferences" -> "Source Code" -> "Code Formatting"

Select code type you want to change formatting for,
Under "Text Style" tab, unclick "Use default settings from 'text file'",
And unclick "Convert tabs to spaces".

I guess there is a text file somewhere where the default settings are stored. I think I saw answers for editing that but not including where to find it. This works for me.